# Laravel Homestead "VM not created" after accidental git pull

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I made an accidental `git pull` on the `~/Homestead` directory rather than my project directory.

After that, I am not able to get any `vagrant` commands to run, all returning the same message:

```
==> homestead-7: VM not created. Moving on...
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the pull successful?

Try and provision with

```
vagrant up --provision
```

If needed you can have the machine rebuild itself completely by destroying the machine first with:

```
vagrant destroy
```

You may also need to re-run the `init.sh` script since the VM updated, that can be done with:

```
sh init.sh
```

However, just be aware that this will overwrite your VagrantFile so you may want to back that up.

Comment: The pull was successful as I don't think I've changed anything under that directory. I try to revert the pull, but the vagrant commands still won't work.

Comment: It seems after reverting the git pull, I was able to run vagrant up again by removing the original vm. Thanks for the answer.